# C/C++ configure of Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

I can't seem to configure NetBeans correctly using MinGW. I did everything according to instructions, I added the paths in Variables. But somehow I still can't get it to work.

I tried to compile my sample program and this is the outpit:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\msgcomm.exe: error while opening "MKDIR=mkdir" for reading: No such file or directory


BUILD FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 53ms)
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given that error, it appears you need the build environment, not just a compiler. For example, you can use [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) to provide the build tools NetBeans/MingW might be expecting.